# Does the second derivative of a convex function exist at all but countably many points?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

I know that the second derivative of a convex function exists almost everywhere ([Alexandrov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_theorem)).

And I know that the first derivative exists everywhere except countably many points ([This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946311/a-convex-function-is-differentiable-at-all-but-countably-many-points)).

So, does the second derivative exist everywhere except countably many points? I'd appreciate a source I can cite, or a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $g(t)$ is a nondecreasing real-valued function, then $f(x)=\int_a^x g(t)\,dt$ is convex.  If $g$ is also continuous, then $f'(x)=g(x)$ everywhere.  If $g(t)$ is the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), then $g$ is nondifferentiable at uncountably many points.

<s>Gap: I do not have a reference or proof handy for showing that $g$ is nondifferentiable at uncountably many points in the Cantor set.</s>

For a reference on the nondifferentiability set of the Cantor function, see Darst's "The Hausdorff Dimension of the Nondifferentiability Set of the Cantor Function is $[\ln(2)/\ln(3)]^2$" ([JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2159830)), which I found in the references on the Wikipedia page linked above.

Comment: I see "integrable" is redundant there.  Here is a reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318407/integral-of-an-increasing-function-is-convex  In the question it is assumed that the integrand is differentiable, but in the accepted answer this is not used.  Continuity of the integrand is not even used.

Comment: I think continuity of the integrand _is_ used: "$F(x)$ is continuous due to the continuity of $f(x)$."

Comment: @DavidK: It is cited unnecessarily, as I have commented there now.  The indefinite integral of a locally Lebesgue integrable function is absolutely continuous.  The indefinite integral of a locally bounded integrable function is locally Lipschitz.  Every nondecreasing function is continuous a.e.. And $g$ in this case is continuous anyway.  Note that at that answer they do not indicate why continuity of $f$ implies continuity of $F$; if one were to work it out I believe local boundedness of $f$ would be a more natural property to use, and that follows from monotonicity.