# Can I apply Jensen Inequality here?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, jensen-inequality

$X$ is a non negative random variable with decreasing density function. Let $U$ be a $Unif(0,2t)$ random variable where $t>0$. For $x>0$ define $G(X)=P(X>x)$. Then show that $$\mathbb{E}(G(U)) \geq G(\mathbb{E}(U))$$

---

So, basically $G(X)=1-F(X)$, where $F(X)$ is the distribution function of $X$. Now, $G'(X)=-f(x)$ , $f(x)$ being the density function of $X$. And, $G''(x)=-f'(x)$ which is positive as $f$ is decreasing. This gives us $G$ to be a convex function and then I apply Jensen inequality to get the proof. But there is a problem. In the question it's not said whether $f$ is differentible or not. So, I have to prove first, that $f$ is differentiable and then I can do the rest.
I don't know how to show this.
Any help or any different method would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require differentiability. The indefinite integral of any integrable decreasing function is concave, so $F=1-G$ is concave and $G$ is convex.

PS: There is link below given by Minus One-Twelfth which has  a neat proof of convexity.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on how to actually prove that statement? Is it a standard theorem?

Comment: @Prof.Shanku Yes, it is well known.

Comment: i don't seem to be able to prove this though it seems intuitively clear. Can you please help me prove it?

Comment: @Prof.Shanku PLeas give me some time. I will add a detailed proof

Comment: See e.g. [Integral of an increasing function is convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318407/integral-of-an-increasing-function-is-convex).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ofcourse! Thank you.

Comment: @Prof.Shanku Now there is no need. The link given by Minus One-Twelfth has   a neat proof.